# Email Sync In Java

Tags: java, oauth

How can I synchronize email using IMAP in java ?
My needs are

- OAuth
  My app will start and download all new email uid. After downloading all email uid, it will delete all email which were deleted from the account.

My main questions are:

- Is there a sdk for that for sync email in java like this way ?
- If not what would be the best way to implement this.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check JavaMail: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html

You can also try Jakarta Email: http://commons.apache.org/email/
This provides higher-level API.

Comment: @ Sir I was looking for any lib which can auto sync emails.